# Неверное исключение элементов из массива

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Задание: Определить, есть ли в целочисленном массиве Q (10) заданное
число Х, и если есть, удалить его (если встречается неоднократно, то
удалить все такие значения), а если нет, добавить в конец массива.

Си

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int size = 5, *Q, i, j, x, count = 0;
    Q = malloc(size * sizeof*Q);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &Q[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", Q[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("Enter number:");
    while(1 != scanf("%d", &x)){
        printf("Incorrect data enter!Try again.");
        while(getchar() != '\n');
    }
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(Q[i] == x){
            count++;
            for(j = i; j < size - 1; j++)
                Q[j] = Q[j + 1];
        }
    }
    if(count){
        size -= count;
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("%d ", Q[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    else{
        size++;
        Q = realloc(Q, size * sizeof*Q);
        if(!Q){
            printf("Error allocate memory!");
            return 0;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if(i == size - 1)
                Q[i] = x;
            printf("%d ", Q[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В результате компиляции происходит неверное исключение элементов:

43

23

65

87

23

43 23 65 87 23

Enter number:23

43 65

Знакомый сказал, что это ошибка индексации, но я не понимаю в чём проблема.

Comment: Что вы делаете в `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- По мере удаления элементов из массива `Q` его размер уменьшается, и в хвосте массива остаются значения, оставшиеся после сдвига элементов. Их не следует удалять, но цикл `for(i = 0; i < size; i++)` никак не учитывает уменьшение размера массива `Q` и продолжает удаление элементов в хвосте. Поэтому счётчик количества удалённых элементов `count` наращивается больше, чем следует.
- Предположим, что элементы массива `Q` с индексами `i` и `i+1` должны быть удалены. На `i`-той итерации цикла `for` все элементы массива `Q` начиная с индекса `i+1` будут сдвинуты на одну позицию левее. Т.е. элемент `i+1`, который необходимо удалить, займёт позицию элемента `i` и на следующей итерации цикла избежит удаления.
- Сдвигать хвост массива на одну позицию левее при каждом удалении — не эффективно. Можно завести два индекса: `dest` — позиция в массиве `Q`, в которую будем копировать элементы, `src` — позиция из которой копируем элементы.
  В цикле перебираем элементы массива. Если наткнулись на элемент массива *не* подлежащий удалению, то копируем его из `src` в `dest` и наращиваем оба индекса.
  Если наткнулись на элемент подлежащий удалению, то ничего не копируем и наращиваем только индекс `src`.
  Примерно так:

```
size_t src = 0, dest = 0;
while (src < size)
{
    if (Q[src] != x)
    {
        Q[dest] = Q[src];
        ++dest;
    }
    ++src;
}

if (src - dest > 0)
    size -= src - dest;
else
{
    ++size;
    int* Q_new = realloc(Q, size * sizeof *Q);
    if (!Q_new)
    {
        free(Q);
        printf("Error allocate memory!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    Q = Q_new;
    Q[size - 1] = x;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    printf("%d ", Q[i]);
putchar('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Массив `Q` изменяется три раза на итерациях 1, 3 и 4. Изменяется - громко сказано. Два последних изменения оставляют массив в прежнем состоянии. Для нас важно значение переменной `count` в конце. Предполагается что `count` считает элементы равные `23`. Их два в исходном массиве. Но массив меняется, последнее значение удваивается и два раза подсчитывается:

> ```
> i           Q          count
> 0    [43 23 65 87 23]    0
> 1    [43 65 87 23 23]    1
> 2    [43 65 87 23 23]    1
> 3    [43 65 87 23 23]    2
> 4    [43 65 87 23 23]    3
> ```

Вот правка, которая починит ваш код. Надо остановить цикл раньше чем кончится массив `Q`:

```
// for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
for(i = 0; i < size - count; i++){
```